# Possible to evaluate GLM in Python/scikit-learn using the Poisson, Gamma, or Tweedie distributions as the family for the error distribution?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, python, scikit-learn, gradient-descent, tweedie-distribution

Trying to learn some Python and Sklearn, but for my work I need to run regressions that use error distributions from the Poisson, Gamma, and especially Tweedie families.

I don't see anything in the documentation about them, but they are in several parts of the R distribution, so I was wondering if anyone has seen implementations anywhere for Python.  It would be extra cool if you can point me towards SGD implementations of the Tweedie distribution!

Comment: The most robust GLM implementations in Python are in [statsmodels]statsmodels.sourceforge.net, though I'm not sure if there are SGD implementations.

Comment: Thanks Trey.  It looks like there's no support for Tweedie, but they do have some discussion of Poisson and Gamma distributions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update (Jan 2023) - sklearn has [Tweedie](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.TweedieRegressor.html), [Poisson](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html), and [gamma](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.GammaRegressor.html) GLMs as of [v 0.23](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.23.html) in May 2020.

---

There is [movement](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5975) to implement generalized linear models with Poisson, gamma, and Tweedie error distributions in scikit-learn.

[Statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Poisson.fit.html) has implementations of generalized linear models with Poisson, Tweedie, and gamma error distributions.

While I'm updating this answer, [Spark ML](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression) also (experimentally) supports Poisson, Tweedie, and gamma distributions.

Comment: I'm working on it: https://github.com/madrury/py-glm

Comment: @MatthewDrury Awesome!

Comment: @MatthewDrury nice! I just started using GLM's, and [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org) has some limitations. Not sure I understand the math fully, but could your [inner-solve](https://github.com/madrury/py-glm/blob/master/glm/glm.py#L205) be replaced with an arbitrary least-squares-type solver? I was thinking this would add flexibility (e.g. pass in [sklearn.ElasticNet](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html) to get scalability/regularization/etc. "for free"?).

Answer (score 3):

H2O has [Generalized Linear Model](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html)s.

They use H2O Frames though, so you can't use Pandas/Numpy directly.